# Key binding for exiting VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I can't seem to find a way to bind a key combination to the Exit menu item. What is the name of its entry in the keybindings panel?

I've tried filtering the list on `"exit"` or `"shutdown"` but none of the returned results seem to be relevant.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be `workbench.action.quit`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! So easy when you know the answer :)